# How to find the data in a cell which appears in more cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet which has increasing rows as data is added.
Using ong column(H) I want to use the last 40 entries to find the value in one of these cells that appears the most times in the column.

I have the following formula to fimd the current last cell  `=LOOKUP(2,1/((H:H)),ROW(H:H))`
and use `=(N154-40)` to find the cell 40 rows up, then `="H"&(N154)` to get the last cell ie `(H178)` and like wise `="H"&(N154-40)` to get start cell ie `(H138)`.

I want to use the values of the above which are in `J154` and `K154` respectively in the formula `=INDEX(J154:K154,MODE(MATCH(J154:K154,J154:K154,0)))` to get the number of cells with the same value?

This doesn't seem to work for me, and have tried different alternatives.

Comment: It looks like J154 and K154 contain cell references NOT the range you want to index. You'll need to use `INDIRECT()`. There may be simpler alternatives.

Comment: I agree with gns100, in your first sample, to get the cell H138, you need to use Indirect function, such as `=INDIRECT("H"&(N154-40))`.

Comment: It might be helpful to see sample data and the expected output (maybe make an example where you look for the cell 4 rows up so the screen caps are manageable)